# Returning the userId from an external script

Tags: users, external-scripts

I have a very simple external php script which will not return the userId. The script is posted below:

```
<?php
include_once "/includes/bootstrap.inc";
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
global $user;
$userId = $user->uid;
echo $userId;
?>
```

This script returns an empty string, and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I have checked to make sure bootstrap.inc is located in the correct directory. I've made sure the directory is accessible. This should be an easy process, but for some reason I just can't return the userId of the currently logged in user..

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($user)`? And what makes you sure your external script shares session with genuine Drupal site?

Comment: var_dump($user) also returns an empty string.You might be right because I'm not even sure it shares the same session, I'm just trying solutions that were posted to previous yet similar questions here.

Comment: It might help if you could tell us where your Drupal and your script are located. Just substitute actual domain with http://example.com if you don't want to make it public (it's about address / directory structure, not about where we can see your site, after all)

Comment: Drupal is located locally at /www/drupal. The script is also located in the root directory, so it shouldn't have any problems accessing the includes folder. I'm almost certain this is not a permissions issue as the includes folder is set to full access.

Comment: But `$user` should be `NULL` or Drupal user object. Empty string makes no sense.